# vb.net large included file causes exception during install

Tags: vb.net

I am currently working on an app, part of which consists of extracting a large rar file.

The rar file is included in the published app with its build action set to content.

The file is roughly 2.6gb in size.

If i run the app in visual studio it all works fine but once i publish i get the following unhandled exception during installation:

value of '-2147483648' is not valid for 'value'. 'value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'

```
************** Exception Text **************
    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value of '-2147483648' is not valid for 'Value'.    'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
    Parameter name: Value
       at System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar.set_Value(Int32 value)
       at System.Deployment.Application.ProgressPiece.UpdateUI()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext,     ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
```

If I choose to continue after the exception the app carries on and installs fine

Answer (score 0):

This error because You have to set `value` between `minimum` and `maximum`.Please ensure that your value

Comment: i have no idea how to do that, could you please advise me of how to correct this issue?